# How to create Blob from local file with require in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, audiobuffer

need help again

I use Webpack and I have audio file, this is how I load it:

```
const file = require('@/assets/filename.mp3')
const blob = new Blob(file) // it doesn't work
```

Now I need to get Blob from it.. I can't understand how to do that.

And the final goal is to get audioBuffer

Thank you for any answers

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work like that. You'll need to fetch the MP3 file from the server with AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Fetch API to request the file from the server. Then read it as an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) and decode it to an [`AudioBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) by using the [`BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) method.

```
/**
 * Get a file, read it as an ArrayBuffer and decode it an AudioBuffer.
 * @param {string} file
 * @returns {Promise<AudioBuffer>}
 */
const fetchAudioBuffer = async file => {
  const audioContext = new AudioContext();

  try {
    const response = await fetch(file);
    const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    return audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

// Fetch the file and decode it as an AudioBuffer.
fetchAudioBuffer('path/to/assets/filename.mp3').then(audioBuffer => {
  // Use your audioBuffer here.
});
```